# Can not install Node module

Tags: react-native

When I want to install a new dependency, I get this error:

```
Can not install Node.js module: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install react-native-datepicker --save

Standard error:
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/akezhan/ Рабочий стол/work/hackathon/BDonor/BDonor-front/node_modules
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.3.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-camera@1.1.0 requires a peer of react@^16.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-gl@1.0.2 requires a peer of react@^16.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-maps@0.21.0 requires a peer of react-native@^0.51 || ^0.52 || ^0.53 || ^0.54 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.6 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permission issue.
Better is to use

```
sudo npm install *package_name*
```

In some situations removing your node_modules folder also works.

```
rm -rf node_modules
```